# Access 2007: Creating an auto-updating record history

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Access newbie here, currently attempting to find a way, through either a macro, query, vba code etc, of updating a table which would store old versions of previous records. I currently have a table (Current_Build) for which I want, every time a record in the table is modified, the version of the record before the update to be sent to another table (Changes_in_Build) which would have multiple copies of the records in Current_Build with the date which they were changed. Have been stuck on this problem for a few days, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you managed to get so far?

Comment: I have managed to, by both form and query, either update the Current_Build table or add a copy to the Changes_In_Build table, but never both

Comment: Does the Changes_in_Build table only have a few fields like FieldChanged,OldValue,NewValue,DateOfChange, etc? Or is it a complete copy of the entire Current_Build record?

Comment: I have attempted it with both of the methods outlined by PowerUser, either will do for my purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your form with the bound controls make sure you have all the values you want to save (including the primary key from the other first table) on your form as bounded controls.  Then when in `Form_AfterUpdate()` place the following code, you will have to update to your controls but I just tested it and it works.

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Changes_in_Build (IdFromTable1,Field1,Field2) VALUES ( " & ID.OldValue & ",'" & Field1.OldValue & "','" & Field2.OldValue & "');"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

This will only update a record once you have moved away from that record to another or you have invoked a manual save through code or macro.If you have more questions let me know.

Comment: Thanks a million Obie, with a little modification this did the job perfectly! Much appreciated

Comment: @DeclanMulligan if this answered your question please mark as correct answer so others will know.